# CSS center single td vertically in table

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to center single td element vertically inside table?

```html
<table style="width:100%; text-align: center">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
  </tr><tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
  </tr><tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td> <!--center this-->
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is example:
https://jsfiddle.net/maykel007/q2ag7ehj/

Comment: what is your mean of vertically?

Comment: your question is not clear ?? mybe you want to use `rowspan="" or colspan=""` ?

Comment: Thanks for answer. I want "94" to be centered inside the last column. Currently it is on the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly.

- You can vertically centre the content within the cell.
- You can make the cell span all four rows

Move the cell to the first row and add a `rowspan` attribute. Then apply the `vertical-align` CSS property.

```css
.x {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" width="500px">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td class="x" rowspan="4">94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using `rowspan`. I did have to change the html a bit; add a `<td>` to all rows, add the value to the first row, set the `colspan` to the amount of `<tr>` it needs to apply to.

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/q2ag7ehj/1/

```
<table style="width:100%; text-align: center">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td rowspan="6">94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td></td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td></td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this JS .each function. I found this in another answer, couldn't find the user to give the credit. If this works fine, do tell I'll search again.

```
var seen = {};
$('#aTable td').each(function() 
{
    var $this = $(this);
    var index = $this.index();
    var txt =  $this.text();
    console.log(txt);
    if (seen[index] === txt) 
    {
        $($this.parent().prev().children()[index]).attr('rowspan', 2);
        $this.hide();
    }
    else 
    {
        seen[index] = txt;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/djhU7/4/

For this to work, the "94"  should be repeated in all the cells (that's the basic idea for vertically aligning the data right? For making it a common value).
After that, what it basically does is, it merges and the single value is retained.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
td:nth-child(3) {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(calc(-100% * (6/2))); /*/number rows is 6 /*/
}
```

```css
td:nth-child(3) {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(calc(-100% * (6/2)));
}
```

```html
<table style="width:500px; text-align: center">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your *94* row is inside a specific line, currently the bottom line, so that's why your 94 is at the bottom.

What you could try is a margin-top, like the following :

```css
.center {
  margin-top : -70px;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%; text-align: center">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
  </tr><tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
  </tr><tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td><p class="center">94</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But it will not be responsive, which means that you will have to figure out each case yourselft to adapt your responsive code.

Comment: Moving things around with pixels is a desperate move that only should be used, IMO, if no other solutions works. As you said, it's non-responsive and it's also not dynamic as the alignment will be wrong if more rows are added to the table.

Comment: I agree 100% but in that case it could work, even if the @RMo solution is, I think, the best